# Observable not getting Refreshed on Submit ? knockoutjs(Fiddle Provided)

Tags: knockout.js

Well i have a scenario where my selected date from TextBox is displaying wrong on change of date(datepicker) in textbox in my alert window on my submit button click  .

On-initial button click you can see the output in alert but later if you change date you will get same date what you got in the 1st instance. observable is not getting refreshed

**Fiddle link :** `:` http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/24/

Any workaround is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have is that you're not adding any callback to value changes, so there is no way knockout will update the observable - because the value inside it doesn't change. Below is my `datepicker` binding handler I used some time ago in one of my projects. It's small and very simple, but should do the job:

```
(function ($, ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            // initialize datePicker with options (not required)
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options);

            // change date handler
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            // update date value
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
})(jQuery, ko);
```

Important note: it works with dates, not strings. So in your view model you should use dates, like this:

```
...
self.Date = ko.observable(new Date('2014-06-03T00:00:00'));//before formatting
...
```

And the markup now should look like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: Date"  />
```

You could also add datepicker options like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: Date, datepickerOptions: {...}"  />
```

Here is full working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/72/).

Comment: Thank you again for showing some way . well i have small queries on above code . what the role of `(function ($, ko)` and `(jQuery, ko);` do ? you using `registerEventHandler` is this one for callback and updating observable like this `observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));` . Thank you

Comment: There are 2 questions here, and 2 answers: 1 - `(function ($, ko)` and `(jQuery, ko);` are considered a good practice to create a separate scope for your code, independent from other javascript code you have in other files - you just pass all external objects (jQuery and knockout) as parameters so you don't have to worry if some script internally will change `$` from jQuery to something else (and your script will stop working). 2 - `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` is just a "knockout" way of registering event handlers, you can use jQuery here, it should work exactly the same.

Comment: good one . i will check the docs to get further grip . thank you man thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get date from observable function, not array

Try this.

It will show you time

```
alert(self.PhoneList()[0].Date());
```

In this case we are getting array from observable array and showing first item Date property

Comment: well ok now try to change the date in text-box and click submit you can observe you get old data not new one . i want to get rid that mainly . cheers

Comment: I was getting here the first value in this PhoneList array. In case that you are talking about you should take last object from PhoneList instead

Comment: actually its observable array you can check fiddle . well i tried it does nothing just keep on getting me old value . i advice once try the fiddle #updated