# Knockout v.3: Subscribing to an observable at a global level containing an object

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I am having some trouble getting an object subscription to update when any of the observable's are updated.

Here is the model I am working with:

```
searchModel = function (startDate, endDate, searchTerm) {
var self = this;
self.StartDate = ko.observable(startDate);
self.EndDate = ko.observable(endDate);
self.SearchTerm = ko.observable(searchTerm);
};
```

Here is the binding handler I am using to update the observable(s) for the datepicker:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(ev.date);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
    }
};
```

This is the extender function I am using to init and subscribe the search model:

```
ko.extenders.getEvents = (function (target, options) {
    function getEvents(target) {
        console.log(target);
    };

    getEvents(target());
    target.subscribe(getEvents);

    return target;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated... In short i would like the page to initialize with the default observable model values (below), and whenever any of the observables in the object are update, subscribe fires off so i can 'do stuff'.

```
this.SearchCriteria = ko.observable(new searchModel('', '', '')).extend({
    getEvents: null
});
```

Here is what I am working with: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h97Mq/)

Comment: It looks to me like the main problem is that the `changeDate` event isn't firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindingHandler is not handling the "changeDate" event.  That is happening in the $(document).ready.

Not sure if this what you are looking for, but, I'd change it up slightly.  I'd bind the knockout on the searchModel and move the bindingHandler out.  You can then 'do stuff' through your searchModel function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor() || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function(ev) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(ev.date);
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
    }
};

var searchModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.startDate = ko.observable();
    self.endDate = ko.observable();
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable();
};

var search = new searchModel();
ko.applyBindings(search);

$('#datepicker1').datepicker();
$('#datepicker2').datepicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J8LCJ/1/

Comment: similar sort of question posted any thoughts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224256/observable-not-getting-refreshed-on-submit-knockoutjsfiddle-provided . cheers Thank you