# Issue pushing selected listitem in observableArray to other observableArray ? fiddle provided

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

well , i am trying to push the list item of a particular observable array on click of `Add to List` button but only if anyone of the radio button is checked else i just need to show a alert check something like that.

Here is my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/69/)

I built the fiddle with near match to what i am looking for . hope its gets you on right mark what i am looking for .

As of now in current fiddle when we click on button its not at all adding even i checked or not don't know whats going on but eventually its getting into click function .

**Well things i been stuck trying so far :**

In case of check box its pretty straight forward to know in a array which listitem with checkbox is checked but in radio button where my observable array will be filled  `DYNAMICALLY` i am unable to find the excat list item with radio button checked .

I stuck at `if` condition in `foreach`

```
if(service.check()) // this one fails me 
        {
          self.addedList.push(service);
            count++;
        }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: Check if you are getting any error in the browser's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio input `checked` binding works a little different, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter.

So you cannot use true/false in your sample, because you actually have 3 values. Here is how you should change your markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="select" data-bind="checked: $parent.checkedCode, value: Code" />
```

And in your view model:

```
self.checkedCode = ko.observable();
self.addToList = function () {
    var count =0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.PhoneList(),function(service){
        if(service.Code() == self.checkedCode())
        {
            self.addedList.push(service);
            count++;
        }

    }); 
    if(count == 0) {alert("Check something to Add");}        
};
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/71/). And if you want to use boolean radio buttons (when there are only 2 possible values), I suggest you to see this great [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/utsvJ/) by Ryan Niemeyer with checkedRadioToBool custom binding.

Comment: works awesome bro . but how come $parent.checkedCode == code ? can you clarify mate .

Comment: Since we specified in our binding `checked: $parent.checkedCode, value: Code`, this observable will keep the currently chosen radio input value (ko sets values on radio inputs to according Codes).

Comment: oh ok that makes sense . thank you again . well just curious is there any way we can restrict something like once added cant be added again ?

Comment: Sure, you can use `ko.utils.arrayFirst()` (see good [article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) on knockout utils) to find first matching element in the array, and if there is none, push current item in collection. P.S. Could you please accept my answer? :)

Comment: oops i tought i accepted ur answer long back anyhow done it now . Thank you your tips helps me to improve

Comment: @supercool You accepted other answer :) Oh, now it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60330/discussion-between-super-cool-and-ilya-luzyanin).

Comment: well if you got time this is my long back posted question still i didnt get what wrong in fiddle . observable not getting refreshed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224256/observable-not-getting-refreshed-on-submit-knockoutjsfiddle-provided

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to have?

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G_sh/JL26Z/70/).

I have changed the following lines

```
       if(service.Check) // this one fails me 
        {
          self.addedList.push(service);
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: Ilya Luzyanin solution is working to my requirement . ty for your time bro